# how to use string as label id c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the text of the label(i) 
as 'i' increase in timer the text of label'i' will change

```
int i =0;  
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string label = "label" + i.ToString();
        Control l = FindControl(label);
        Label labeli = (Label)l;
        labeli.Text = "somthing";
        i++;
    }
```

but it shows the error

> "the name 'FindControl' does not exist in current context"

is the code incorrect or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Where did you define "i" and "FindControl"? Update your question.

Comment: I updated it but i did't understand how to define "FindControl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
var lbl = this.Controls.Find(label, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
```

Then you should check if `lbl` is not null and assign a value to it's `Name` property.

```
if(lbl != null)
{
    lbl.Text = "something";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
Label label = Label label = this.Controls
                    .OfType<Label>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == labelName);

if (label != null) label.Text = "Something";
```

Or iterate through all Labels which starts with label:

```
var  labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("label"));

foreach (Label label in labels) {
      label.Text = "somthing";
}
```

Or if you'd like to find labels1-6:

```
var labels = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 6)
    .Select(i => 
        this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name == "label" + i));
```